# Tensorflow Build Error on Windows 10

Tags: windows, tensorflow

System information

**OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04):** Windows 10

**TensorFlow installed from (source or binary):** Source from master branch

**Python version:** 3.6.2

**Bazel version (if compiling from source):** cmake 3.9.4

**CUDA/cuDNN version:** CUDA 9.0/cuDNN 7

**GPU model and memory:** GTX 1080

**Exact command to reproduce:**

`MSBuild /filelogger /m:4 /p:Configuration=Release tf_python_build_pip_package.vcxproj`

I have been trying to build the TensorFlow pip package. For some reason, while I have verified that the build is able to clone the other git repos, the jsoncpp one seems to be killing my build.

```
42>CustomBuild: Creating directories for 'jsoncpp'
42>CustomBuild: Performing download step (git clone) for 'jsoncpp'
42>CustomBuild: fatal: could not create work tree dir 'jsoncpp': Permission denied
42>CustomBuild: fatal: could not create work tree dir 'jsoncpp': Permission denied
42>CustomBuild: fatal: could not create work tree dir 'jsoncpp': Permission denied
42>CustomBuild: -- Had to git clone more than once: 3 times.
42>CustomBuild: CMake Error at     C:/Users/Bryce/Documents/Programming/os_clones/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/cmake/build/jsoncpp/tmp/jsoncpp-gitclone.cmake:66 (message): Failed to clone repository: 'https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp.git'
```

And later on,

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(171,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1. [C:\Users\Bryce\Documents\Programming\os_clones\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\jsoncpp.vcxproj]
```

[msbuild.log](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/files/1404600/msbuild.log)

Any ideas on what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you in Administrator cmd mode, it seems you don't have write permission, did you try it?

Comment: I ended up just building the project in Ubuntu and working from there.  I believe I was running the command prompt as Admin.  The thing I could not figure out was why the script was able to clone the other repos, but only failed for this one.